# Restore model tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm testing the option to save the model and then restore it in another instance of python. For that what I'm doing is to use this code to save the model:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver([weights0,weights1,weights2,syn0,bias0,syn1,bias1],max_to_keep = 2)
saver.save(sess, '..\\places365_TFG\\models\\CNNFinalModel', global_step=l)
```

And then in another instance of python I do this:

```
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('..\\places365_TFG\\models\\CNNFinalModel-67.meta')
new_saver.restore(sess, 
tf.train.latest_checkpoint('..\\places365_TFG\\models\\./'))
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
weights0 = graph.get_tensor_by_name("weights0:0")
```

To check if the value of weights0 is well restored I do:

```
sess.run(weights0)
```

The variable weights0 was initialized like this:

```
def weight_variable(shape,name):
   initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1, name=name)
   return tf.Variable(initial)

weights0 = weight_variable([3,3,3,16], name='weights0')
```

The problem I see is that, every time I execute this, the value of weigths0 change. I suppose it is because is defined as variable, but I want to keep the value I saved from my original neural network.

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like `weight0` depends on some calculation. Can you please post the code where `weight0` is defined?

Comment: @PeterSzoldan Sure! I've edited the question with it. Thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: Do you do any `sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )` between the runs? Those would re-initialize the variable with random numbers. Otherwise looks all right to me, except I'd use `tf.get_variable()` not `tf.Variable()` to create it first, but that should not cause this issue.

Comment: @PeterSzoldan No I don't do initializer. Should I initialize the variable in some other way before doing graph.getTensorbyname? Can I just copy the value in a constant value o something like that?

Comment: No, you load the value, so you should NOT initialize, you're right. I was just guessing that maybe you - mistakenly - do initialize, and that causes the issue. From what I see the issue should not occur. The bug is in some other part of the code. So maybe you should post as much of it as possible.